# Multiple df operation in spark at once

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have following pandas code want to convert to pyspark

```
df[df['A'].isna()]['B'].value_counts()
```

In separate pyspark

```
df.filter(df["A"].isNull())

df.groupBy('B').count().orderBy('count').show()
```

Is there any way that I can combine these two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chain the methods:

```
df.filter(df["A"].isNull()).groupBy('B').count().orderBy('count').show()
```

Or use this syntax:

```
df[df['A'].isNull()].groupBy('B').count().orderBy('count').show()
```